# MATCH relevance for records spanning multiple rows (cannot use GROUP_CONCAT with MATCH together)

Tags: mysql

I'm having MySQL problems and I'm in need of a beer lunch. I wanted to do a query like this:

`SELECT MATCH(some_string) AGAINST ('beer lunch') FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(some_column) AS some_string FROM myrealtable) AS mytablealias;`

Unfortunately I discovered I cannot do a FULLTEXT MATCH against a GROUP_CONCAT column since the FULLTEXT index exists for the original column (some_column) only and not in the concatenated column (some_string) in the alias table.

I really need to do a FULLTEXT search and generate a relevance score for concatenated strings that are broken across multiple rows in my table.

Here's a little thought experiment that I put together to study the relevance problem. Let's start with a table that has the concatenated strings:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| table_id | concat_string                                                                       |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | I like beer Beer is a healthy choice My brother drinks beer for lunch every day     |
|        2 | I like juice Juice is a healthier choice My brother drinks beer for lunch every day |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I do the following MATCH query on this table: `SELECT table_id,MATCH(concat_string) AGAINST('beer lunch') AS score FROM myconcattable;` and I get the following relevance scores:

```
+----------+----------------------------+
| table_id | score                      |
+----------+----------------------------+
|        1 | 0.000000007543713209656744 |
|        2 | 0.000000003771856604828372 |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

Clearly the first row is far more relevant than the second when searching for "beer lunch" ... but the problem is that my strings are broken across multiple rows that need to be grouped according to a foreign key (foreign_id). Here's what my table really looks like:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| table_id | some_string                                | foreign_id |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
|        1 | I like beer                                |          1 |
|        2 | Beer is a healthy choice                   |          1 |
|        3 | My brother drinks beer for lunch every day |          1 |
|        4 | I like juice                               |          2 |
|        5 | Juice is a healthier choice                |          2 |
|        6 | My brother drinks beer for lunch every day |          2 |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

So now let's try the query (`SELECT table_id,MATCH(some_string) AGAINST('beer lunch') AS score, foreign_id FROM mybrokentable;`) on this table:

```
+----------+----------------------+------------+
| table_id | score                | foreign_id |
+----------+----------------------+------------+
|        1 | 0.031008131802082062 |          1 |
|        2 | 0.031008131802082062 |          1 |
|        3 |  0.25865283608436584 |          1 |
|        4 |                    0 |          2 |
|        5 |                    0 |          2 |
|        6 |  0.25865283608436584 |          2 |
+----------+----------------------+------------+
```

OK, so if I add up the scores as a sum, then foreign_id 1 looks a bit more relevant than foreign_id 2, but it is not very accurate compared to when the strings were concatenated into one table.

Ideally, I'd like to devise a query that would generate a relevance score for the foreign ids like this:

```
+----------------------------+------------+
| score                      | foreign_id |
+----------------------------+------------+
| 0.000000007543713209656744 |          1 |
| 0.000000003771856604828372 |          2 |
+----------------------------+------------+
```

Any ideas of what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try summing the scores in your individual phrase matches, like so, with a subquery.  You'll have to experiment to see if it gives you the result you need.

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS total_score,
       foreign_id
  FROM (
     SELECT table_id,
            MATCH(some_string) AGAINST('beer lunch') AS score, 
            foreign_id 
       FROM phrase
       ) AS scores
 GROUP BY foreign_id
 ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

I used BOOLEAN MODE in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/355b1/1/0 because ordinary fulltext search does odd things with stopwords on small samples of text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ollie. This is extremely helpful. I tried your Fiddle and noticed that it returns total scores (4, 2) that have similar proportions to my first test above, where 0.0000000075 is approximately twice 0.0000000037. So the BOOLEAN MODE search seems to behave the way I want it ... except I am doing this FULLTEXT search on an InnoDB table (MySQL 5.6). In your Fiddle, I changed the MySQL version to 5.6.6 and the table engine to InnoDB. Sure enough, it returns decimals instead of booleans ... do you know if there's any way around this issue in InnoDB?

Comment: I don't know anything about 5.6's InnoDB fulltext, sorry.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Your answer generally works for me, although it would have been nice to use the BOOLEAN functionality.